# Android App Layout

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm developing an android app for 2.2 ver.

My app must hav such structure:

`[ Spinner here (fixed height) ]`

`[ ListView (not-fixed height) ]`

`[ ImageView    (fixed-height) ]`

I have to use only portrait orientation.

I use linearLayout for it. How can I calculate listView height to show spinner on the top of the screen, imageview on the bottom, and listview cover all free space, but not push others away from field of view.

It will be cool to make it dinamic for lots of screen resolutions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative layout to accomplish what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

By doing this listview will adjust its size so that it fits between the spinner and imageview on your screen

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the android:layout_weight attribute on the variable-height item, so it fills the available space.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the `ListView` still covering the image in this example? It seems like it does.

Comment: Try it and you'll see. The layout is using layout_weight, which specifies the relative ratios between views. 0 means fixed size, anything greater (e.g. the 1 I used) allows it to stretch. So if the first and third views are fixed sizes use wrap_content on their height, or set an explicit height, e.g. 30dp

Comment: I was just checking it without putting anything in the layouts and it was covering, but i will try adding stuff to the layout and see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this, using `weights`. This may be the easiest approach.

You can put in to the `weight` a percentage of the screen you would like it to take up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="80"></ListView>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
Now that i think about it, this will "fix" the size of all the widgets. They will be "fixed" at percentages of the screen. This will scale well with other screen sizes, but you did say you wanted `ListView` to not be fixed.